# Google Charts only annotation text on first found high/low value

Tags: charts, annotations, google-visualization

I built a weatherstation out of an rpi zero, which then saves measuments in a MariaDB database, and then displays the data in Google Charts on a locally hosted server. I have set up some code to display annotation text at todays highest and lowest values for each measure. My problem is, if the same value is repeated, it puts the annotation text there again, i.e. this night wasn't windy at all, so it measured 0m/s all night, and you can see the result in the picture below.
[image]

The code used for the annotation text is as follows:

```
    windview.setColumns([0,1,
    {
    role: "annotation",
    type: "string",
    calc: function (dt, row) { 
        var windrange = dt.getColumnRange(1);
        var windcurVal = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
        if(windcurVal == windrange.min || windcurVal == windrange.max)
            return ((windcurVal)+ 'm/s'); 
        return null; 
        }
    }
]);
```

What i want to achieve is that it only displays 0m/s the first time, and have tried a few ways of doing so, but nothing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when a match is found,
we can use `getFilteredRows` to make sure it is the first row with that value.

```
windview.setColumns([0, 1, {
  role: "annotation",
  type: "string",
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var windrange = dt.getColumnRange(1);
    var windcurVal = dt.getValue(row, 1);
    var windcurFmt = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
    if ((windcurVal === windrange.min) || (windcurVal === windrange.max)) {
      var rows = dt.getFilteredRows([{
        column: 1,
        value: windcurVal
      }]);
      if ((rows.length > 0) && (rows[0] === row)) {
        return ((windcurFmt) + 'm/s');
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'y0'],
    [0, 0],
    [1, 0],
    [2, 0],
    [3, 1],
    [4, 1],
    [5, 2],
    [6, 2],
    [7, 3],
    [8, 3],
    [9, 3]
  ]);

  var windview = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  windview.setColumns([0, 1, {
    role: "annotation",
    type: "string",
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      var windrange = dt.getColumnRange(1);
      var windcurVal = dt.getValue(row, 1);
      var windcurFmt = dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1);
      if ((windcurVal === windrange.min) || (windcurVal === windrange.max)) {
        var rows = dt.getFilteredRows([{
          column: 1,
          value: windcurVal
        }]);
        if ((rows.length > 0) && (rows[0] === row)) {
          return ((windcurFmt) + 'm/s');
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  }]);

  var options = {
    legend: 'none',
    vAxis: {
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(windview, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```